# Is displayMetrix xdpi and ydpi accurate?

Tags: android

Can the xdpi and ydpi settings be relied upon to accurately represent the physical pixels in once inch of screen space?  I need this to be accurate for some display code I'm writing.  I realize the documention says that this is the case, but I need to know if individual handsets get this right MOST OF THE TIME.

I know I can alternately use "densitiy" which will give me 120, 160, 240 steps of DPI, but an exact dpi would be much better.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, that is not possible. The Android documentation of the DisplayMetrics class is misleading. It sucks, I know.

Answer (score 1):

I should add that xdpi and ydpi seem to be wrong on all phones I've tried.

Comment: I agree with Andy. I tried xdpi and ydpi on my Nexus 7 and they give my 195.4 for xdpi and 200.7 for ydpi which in turn both should be 213 :)